# agm google maps, multiple markers with same coordinates

Tags: angular, google-maps

I need to display list of users. The demand is to display users only to the level of their city. So there might be a situation where I have hundreds of users in the same location.

I thought of using  agm-marker-cluster and by clicking of the cluster to display a list of all the users in this location but this option is not available to the agm-marker-cluster.

Maybe anyone as an idea how to implement such a case?